# Complex validation in Jsonnet library

Tags: jsonnet

What I'm trying to do is create a libsonnet library with some complex validation on the inputs, but I'm not sure how to implement this in the `libsonnet` file without getting `null` back.

I'm trying to generate API calls for [Hosted Graphite's Alerts API](https://www.hostedgraphite.com/docs/alerting/alerts_api.html) using Jsonnet. The idea being is that we can store all of our alerts in version control, and update them in a CI / CD pipeline. I want to prevent errors, so I've implemented some complex validation based on what the above API spec defines. I have the following saved as `alerts.libsonnet`:

```
local alert_criteria_types = [
  'above',
  'below',
  'missing',
  'outside_bounds',
];

local notification_types_strings = [
  'state_change',
];

local notification_types_arrays = [
  'every',
  'state_change',
];

local on_query_failure_types = [
  'ignore',
  'notify',
  null,
];

{
  local HostedGraphiteAlerts = self,

  new(
    name,
    metric,
    alert_criteria_type,
    additional_alert_criteria={},
    additional_criteria={},
    expression='a',
    scheduled_mutes=[],
    notification_channels=['Email me'],
    notification_type=null,
    info=null,
    on_query_failure='notify',
  )::

    // Simple checks
    assert std.member(alert_criteria_types, alert_criteria_type) : "Input 'alert_criteria_type' is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', alert_criteria_types);
    assert std.member(on_query_failure_types, on_query_failure) : "Input 'on_query_failure_type' is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', on_query_failure_types);

    // Advanced checks
    if notification_type != null && std.isString(notification_type) then
        assert std.member(notification_types_strings, notification_type) : "Input 'notification_type' is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', notification_types_strings);

    if notification_type != null && std.isArray(notification_type) then
      assert std.member(notification_types_arrays, notification_type[0]) : "Input 'notification_type' is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', notification_types_arrays);

    if notification_type != null && std.isArray(notification_type) then
        assert std.member(notification_types_arrays, notification_type[0]) : "Input 'notification_type' is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', notification_types_arrays);

    if notification_type != null && std.isArray(notification_type) && notification_type[0] == 'every' then
        assert notification_type[1] != null : "Input 'notification_type' cannot have an empty entry for 'time_in_minutes' for notification type 'every'.";

    if notification_type != null && std.isArray(notification_type) && notification_type[0] == 'every' then
        assert std.isNumber(notification_type[1]) : "Input 'notification_type' must have a JSON 'number' type for notification type 'every'.";

    // Main
    {
      name: name,
      metric: metric,
      alert_criteria: {
        type: alert_criteria_type,
      } + additional_alert_criteria,
      additional_criteria: additional_criteria,
      expression: expression,
      scheduled_mutes: scheduled_mutes,
      notification_channels: notification_channels,
      notification_type: notification_type,
      info: info,
      on_query_failure: on_query_failure,
    },
}
```

This passes a basic `jsonnetfmt` check, but the problem is when I go to use it in an `alerts.jsonnet` file like so:

```
local alerts = (import 'hosted_graphite.libsonnet').alerts;

alerts.new(
  name='something',
  metric='some.graphite.metric',
  alert_criteria_type='below',
)
```

This simply returns `null`:

```sh
$ jsonnet hosted_graphite/alerts.jsonnet
null
```

I know this is because it's taking the value of the first `assert` statement. But how else can this be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware that `jsonnet` is not an imperative language, don't expect those `if` lines to get evaluated as if where part of a script.
Think of assertions as a "virtual" / invisible field that must always evaluate to `true`

Below implements what (I think) you're after:

### `hosted_graphite.libsonnet`

```
local alert_criteria_types = [
  'above',
  'below',
  'missing',
  'outside_bounds',
];

local notification_types_strings = [
  'state_change',
];

local notification_types_arrays = [
  'every',
  'state_change',
];

local on_query_failure_types = [
  'ignore',
  'notify',
  null,
];

{
  local HostedGraphiteAlerts = self,

  new(
    name,
    metric,
    alert_criteria_type,
    additional_alert_criteria={},
    additional_criteria={},
    expression='a',
    scheduled_mutes=[],
    notification_channels=['Email me'],
    notification_type=null,
    info=null,
    on_query_failure='notify',
  )::

    // Main
    {
      name: name,
      metric: metric,
      alert_criteria: {
        type: alert_criteria_type,
      } + additional_alert_criteria,
      additional_criteria: additional_criteria,
      expression: expression,
      scheduled_mutes: scheduled_mutes,
      notification_channels: notification_channels,
      notification_type: notification_type,
      info: info,
      on_query_failure: on_query_failure,

      // Simple checks
      assert std.member(alert_criteria_types, self.alert_criteria.type) : (
        "Input 'alert_criteria_type' is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', alert_criteria_types)
      ),
      assert std.member(on_query_failure_types, self.on_query_failure) : (
        "Input 'on_query_failure_type' is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', on_query_failure_types)
      ),

      // Advanced checks:
      // - 1st line is a conditional that must be false ('A||B' construct) to get 2nd line evaluated
      // - 2nd line is the "final" type/value check, must be true
      assert (self.notification_type == null || !std.isString(self.notification_type) ||
              std.member(notification_types_strings, self.notification_type)) : (
        "Input 'notification_type' string is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', notification_types_strings)
      ),
      assert (self.notification_type == null || !std.isArray(self.notification_type) ||
              std.member(notification_types_arrays, self.notification_type[0])) : (
        "Input 'notification_type' array is not one of the types: %s." % std.join(', ', notification_types_arrays)
      ),
      assert (self.notification_type == null || !std.isArray(self.notification_type) ||
              self.notification_type != ['every', null]) : (
        "Input 'notification_type' cannot have an empty entry for 'time_in_minutes' for notification type 'every'."
      ),
      assert (self.notification_type == null || !std.isArray(self.notification_type) ||
              [self.notification_type[0], std.isNumber(self.notification_type[1])] == ['every', true]) : (
        "Input 'notification_type' must have a JSON 'number' type for notification type 'every'."
      ),
    },
}
```

### `alerts.jsonnet`

```
local alerts = (import 'hosted_graphite.libsonnet');

{
  a0: alerts.new(
    name='something',
    metric='some.graphite.metric',
    alert_criteria_type='below',
  ),
  a1: alerts.new(
    name='something',
    metric='some.graphite.metric',
    alert_criteria_type='below',
    notification_type='state_change',
  ),
  a2: alerts.new(
    name='something',
    metric='some.graphite.metric',
    alert_criteria_type='below',
    notification_type=['every', 10],
  ),
}
```

Note that I'm using `self.<field>` rather than the function parameter, it's a good pattern to allow derivation/overriding while still getting the assertions evaluated.

BTW I'd also recommend looking at https://cuelang.org/, which plays in the same field as `jsonnet` **but** with type-checking being integral part of the language.

Comment: obviously use `jsonnet alerts.jsonnet` to get the manifested output

Comment: Thank you so much @jjo ! Great explanation.